# Which should be used between Referenced and Embedded document in the Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

I want to use the Couchbase noSQL database. But, I am confused about which document structure used Referenced and Embedded documents.

I have three entity.

1. Appointment
2. Invoice of appointment.
3. Payment detail of Invoice. (One to Many )

So, Which document structure should I use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a very broad question with no "right" answer. You need to take into account your access patterns (i.e. how are you going to typically write and retrieve your data) as well as the structure of the data as you've laid out.

As an example, I think it's entirely possible that all of these can go together in a single document:

```
key: appointment::123

{
   "date": "2018-01-29",
   "place": "123 main st",
   "invoice": {
      "date": "2018-01-30",
      "due": "2018-02-28",
      "items": [
          { "desc": "widget", "quantity": 2, "price":3.99 },
          { "desc": "foo", "quantity": 1, "price":24.99 },
          { "desc": "bar", "quantity": 3, "price":5.00 }
      ]
   }
```

Your question is tagged with both CouchDb and Couchbase, so I'm not sure which you plan to use. However, if you go with Couchbase, I know that [subdocument operations](https://blog.couchbase.com/sub-document-api-in-couchbase-server-4-5-with-the-net-sdk-revisted/) are available to you (as of Couchbase Server 4.5). That is, if you only need a *part* of the document, you don't have to retrieve the *entire* document every time. This can be helpful as the documents get bigger. I don't know if the same sort of thing is available in CouchDb (it might be called something different). Also, Couchbase has a full SQL implementation, so you can query your data no matter what model you end up using.

Comment: I have used Couchbase Server.

Comment: How can I find the only appointment or invoice documents for a particular user in the Couchbase?

Comment: This is really a separate question, but: Supposing you have a field `"user": "jayd"` in your appointment document. You could create an index on that user field and use a N1QL query like `SELECT a.* FROM appointments a WHERE a.user = 'jayd'`

Comment: Or if you don't want to use N1QL, you could create a lookup document with a key like jayd::appointments, which would itself contain a list of document IDs. Again, it all depends on your use case access patterns.